# Smiirl Fliike Board

Tags: board

[image]

Hi

Does anyone know what type of board that Smiirl uses for their Facebook counter? Is it a Arduino? Or something else

Best regards

Comment: Looks like a slice of a trunk rather than a board. Probably Pinus Sylvestris, judging by the texture of the bark.

Comment: @BrianDrummond not so sure. See my answer.

Comment: Beagle bone black maybe, or aurdino.

Answer (score 4):

As Brian said:

> Looks like a trunk rather than a board. Probably Pinus Sylvestris, judging by the texture of the bark

I respectfully have to disagree.

Though it's hard to estimate the size of structures out of focus in this image, I'd say that for a common Scot's pine, the bark isn't flakey enough, by far.

But then again, this might really very likely be a pine species; I'm at least very certain this is timber:

[image: identified as wood]

Now, but what kind of wood is it, then?

Well, I went to the [Smiirl website](https://www.smiirl.com/) (never heard of that before), and I found this fine photo of a confused cafeteria employee in a bike workshop with furniture of highly questionable stability. Also, he has a problem with people putting pictures of objects into his photos which don't match any of the scenery's light conditions, but that's a problem for another day:

[image: fine photo of a confused cafeteria employee in a bike workshop with furniture of highly questionable stability]

Inspecting the wood on the table in the front left more closely, I came to the conclusion that it's probably

- made of the same wood as the trunk, as it's also used to put one of these strange devices on top, and
- that I *knew* [I've seen that same grain of wood elsewhere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRlBtabKRFM):

[image: Quilted Northern Rustic Weave]

So, even if we can't find exactly the type of wood used in your picture, we can at least come to a conclusion on the qualities of the material you're looking for:

- should be wood
- high absorbtion of liquids
- **must** look "rustic", whatever that means. You might want to ask the confused cafeteria employee.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is some major trolling, major misunderstanding, or just major derp. Either way, good on you Marcus.